# R shell.exec requires full file path

Tags: r

I installed R and RStudio this week on a new Windows 10 machine. I want to use this R code to launch Excel and open a CSV file that is in a subdirectory of the current working directory:

```
file <- "example.csv"
sub_dir <- "subdirectory"
shell.exec(file.path(sub_dir, file))
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in shell.exec(file.path(sub_dir, file)) : 
  'subdirectory/example.csv' not found
```

However, if I provide `shell.exec` with the full file path, this code works as expected:

```
shell.exec(file.path(getwd(), sub_dir, file))
```

The documentation for `shell.exec` states:

> The path in file is interpreted relative to the current working
>   directory.
>
> R versions 2.13.0 and earlier interpreted file relative to the R home
>   directory, so a complete path was usually needed.

Why doesn't my original code (without `getwd`) not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be related to the path separator in some wacky way. Below, I specify the the file path separator as `\` and the command executes as expected. You could keep your call to `file.path()` and simply wrap in `normalizePath()` as another option.

```r
file <- "example.csv"
sub_dir <- "subdirectory"
dir.create(sub_dir)
writeLines("myfile",file.path(sub_dir, file))
# Works
shell.exec(file.path(sub_dir, file, fsep = "\\"))
shell.exec(file.path(sub_dir, file))
#> Error in shell.exec(file.path(sub_dir, file)): 'subdirectory/example.csv' not found
```

Comment: `normalizePath` substitutes forward slashes and completes the full path. I'll just stick with `getwd` and submit a bug/documentation error report.

Comment: It may complete the path, but shouldnt use forward slashes if you are on windows. Which, AFAICT, is the only system on which shell.exec works. Also, my other suggestion does not complete full path.

Comment: To be clear, I agree with you that  shell.exec does not work as documented.

Comment: I wasn't clear in my previous comment. I should have said that normalizePath substitutes forward slashes with backslashes; normalizePath(file.path(sub_dir, file)) generates "C:\\path_to_current_working_directory\\subdirecotry\\example.csv"